# FIleObserver NoSuchMethodError in Android 10

Tags: android, crash, fileobserver

I have a `FileObserver(File dir)` that works perfectly in Android11, but crashes badly in Android10 with the following LogCat **even when I try to access the own APP private folder (external sdcard)**:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24651): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/io/File;)V
      in class Landroid/os/FileObserver; or its super classes (declaration of
      'android.os.FileObserver' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime(24651):     at com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser$1.<init>(FileChooser.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime(24651):     at com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser.watchdir(FileChooser.java:570)
E/AndroidRuntime(24651):     at com.floritfoto.apps.xvf.FileChooser.access$500(FileChooser.java:53)
```

My code is pretty simple:

```
private void watchdir(final File dir) {
    if (observer != null) {
        observer.stopWatching();
        observer = null;
    }
    observer = new FileObserver(dir) {   // <===== CRASHES HERE
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;
            ....
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
}
```

Changing `observer = new FileObserver(dir)` with `observer = new FileObserver(dir.getAbsolutePath())` works fine, but  `FileObserver(String path)` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/os/FileObserver).

My app has `compileSdkVersion 31`, `targetSdkVersion 31`, and `minSdkVersion 14`.

At least to some extent this error [has been reported before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63169982/fileobserver-android-10-issue), but no solution has been provided yet.

**EDIT:** The crash is in Android 9, not 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileObserver(File)` is new to API Level 29](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/os/FileObserver#FileObserver(java.io.File)). Your `minSdkVersion` is 14. Your code will crash with this error on API Level 28 and lower. You should be getting Lint warnings and the like warning you that `FileObserver(File)` is newer than your `minSdkVersion`.

Your options are:

1. Use `FileObserver(String)` on all API levels, despite the deprecation warning.
2. Use `FileObserver(String)` on API Levels 14-28 and use `FileObserver(File)` on API Level 29+, using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to determine the API level of the device your app is running on.
3. Set your `minSdkVersion` to 29.
4. Only use `FileObserver` on API Level 29+, and skip whatever features depend on it on older devices.

Comment: Strange. I get no lint warnings (in any part of my code, actually). I guess you meant `FileObserver` instead of `FileProvider`? But you are right, the crash was in Android 9, not 10. Anyway, I am using your option 2.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: Oops, yes, I meant `FileObserver` -- I will fix up the answer!

Comment: I wonder why I didn't get any lint warnings... This is the kind of things that Studio catches easily by default. Maybe I have something wrong configured in the inspections?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: "This is the kind of things that Studio catches easily by default" -- I was rather surprised that you got caught by this. "Maybe I have something wrong configured in the inspections?" -- possibly. Or, perhaps you already have an annotation for this scenario on the class or method, from something else, that had the side effect of suppressing the warning for this new API usage.

Comment: Very strange. NewApi inspection is enabled, and there is no @SuppressLint in that class. This error was already reported before. Maybe there is a bug in the Lint inspection that prevents catching this...?